# Click-triggered ads are annoying

Tags: support, virus

It appears that this is enabled recently. The first mouse click on any hyperlink on a stack exchange site always redirect to

> http://onclickads.net/afu.php?zoneid=658311

Personally I find this extremely annoying. It has never been this way since Stack Overflow started. The on-click ad behavior gives me a very negative impression of the Stack Exchange network. In fact, it encourages me to visit less often, which means less new questions and less answers.

Worse still, every stack exchange site on the network counts as a new site. So, if I visit SuperUser and get the ad, then visit ServerFault later, I will still get the ad on the first click.

Please turn off this feature......you are driving users away, literally.

Comment: What?.. I haven't noticed that...

Comment: It seems your computer is infected with some kind of malware.

Comment: ^What @Glorfindel says. There're no such "Click-triggered ads".

Comment: This is also reproducible on phone.

Comment: Wtf, really. Then it's your internet provider.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this on 3 machines - desktop, laptop + VM.

Comment: The funny fact is that all other sites I browse are not affected......

Comment: Time to get a new internet provider.  Or, figure out what site you're browsing that's infecting all of your devices.

Comment: Continued here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126745/stack-exchanges-javascript-is-malicious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this page](http://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise) tells us, Stack Overflow lets advertisers use banners or sponsor tags.

> [image]

So it's either your internet provider, or viruses that you've got somewhere.